# try catch or async awaiit in useeffect for jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I am running my first unit tests in `JEST`. I installed `Jest Fetch Mock` but I still receive an error, "`The promise rejected with reason FetchError`".

I did some reading, and I guess that I need to add an `async` `await` or a `try` `catch`. Can someone help me with this?

This is the `fetch` I am making in `useEffect`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    
    fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-01-10&sort=stars&order=desc")
    .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [500]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this ,

```
 const [data, setData] = useState(null);
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 useEffect(async() => {
   setLoading(true)
   try{
        const data = await 
          fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories? 
              q=created:%3E2017-01- 
         10&sort=stars&order=desc")
    const json = await data.json();
    if(json){
        setData(json)
        setLoading(false)
      } 
     }catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    }
    
   }, [500]);
```

Comment: You need to add `data = await data.json()`

Comment: Yeah , you are right. My mistake. I edited my code .

Comment: hmm keeps flagging with unexpected token. Can't identify where though. https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-mountain-5n0i5?file=/src/new.js

Comment: @shar27 i edited the code... please try it.

Comment: Do you know how to unit test this code with jest in react?

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [data, setData] = useState(null);
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 useEffect(async() => {
   setLoading(true)
   try{
        const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-01-10&sort=stars&order=desc")
        const data = await res.json()
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
     }catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    
   }, [500]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better

const fetchList = async () => {

const newList  =  await fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-01-10&sort=stars&order=desc")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
setData(data)
setLoading(false)
})
}
fetchList()
}, [500]);